# -mno-cygwin : gcc building Mercurial (Windows 2000)

Tags: c, gcc, mercurial

Because the Mercurial Installer will not work on an old Windows 2000 system, I'm trying to build it from source. Its complaining that the C Compiler doesn't recognize the option **-mno-cygwin**. My version of gcc is 4.6.1. and MinGw is only two months old.

Followed these steps: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

```
F:\mercurial-2.0.2>python setup.py build
running build
running build_mo
warning: hgbuildmo: could not find msgfmt executable, no translations will be built

running build_py
package init file 'mercurial\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'mercurial\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
building 'mercurial.base85' extension
f:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -If:\python27\include 
-If:\python27\PC -c mercurial/base85.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\mercurial\base85.o
**cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'**
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Try installing a new version of MinGW (if that still works on Win2K).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [comment by a TDM-GCC MinGW distro developer](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3413937&group_id=200665&atid=974439):

> As of the 4.6 series, GCC no longer accepts many unrecognized options
>   or flags. TDM-GCC has never "supported" -mno-cygwin; now, it will
>   complain about it. This is also true for libtool flags such as
>   "-no-undefined".

So you may have to use a somewhat older GCC version that will ignore the meaningless option, or fix the build scripts so they don't use that flag (which would never be necessary with the MinGW compiler anyway).

As a follow-on note, it looks like the Cygwin compiler stopped supporting `-mno-cygwin` starting with GCC 4: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-03/msg00802.html

So that option has been more or less useless for a couple years.

Comment: hmm I can't find it referenced in the mercurial source tree

Comment: I think you need to look at the 'Distutils' configuration files - a starting point for info is here: http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#inst-config-files  But I think you'll need to look at the actual config files and/or the “Reference” section of the “Distributing Python Modules” manual.

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster: Take a look in the `Lib\distutils\cygwincompiler.py` script wherever your Python distribution is installed.  It looks like that's where the `-mno-cygwin` option is put in place.

Comment: @Micheal Yeah thanks. I had already fixed the compiler python code and built the optimized version. Moved on to a new problem now! <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935063/couldnt-find-mercurial-libraries-windows-2000>

Answer (score 0):

You not to forget this step before running "python setup.py build"?

If using mingw, a setup.cfg needs to be created which directs setuptools to use it:

```
cd mercurial
echo [build] > setup.cfg
echo compiler=mingw32 >> setup.cfg
```