# couldn't find mercurial libraries : Windows 2000

Tags: windows, mercurial

I think I have studied all the duplicates. I have built Mercurial 2.0.2 and I am using Python27. When I run `hg`, I get this error:

> abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [f:\python27\Lib\site-packages      f:python27\Scripts C:\WINNT\System32\python27.zip f:\python27\DLLs f:\python27\lib f:\python27\lib\plat-win f:\python27\lib\lib-tk f:\python27 f:\python27\lib\site-packages]

Directory of F:\Python27\Lib\site-packages:

```
08/03/2011  09:39                  121 README.txt

18/01/2012  20:24       <DIR>          mercurial

18/01/2012  20:24       <DIR>          hgext

19/01/2012  12:35                  250 mercurial-unknown-py2.7.egg-info

               2 File(s)            371 bytes
```

Comment: Still using Windows 2000? - Anyways, have you tried installing the precompiled TortoiseHg?

Comment: Its a 12 year old machine! I have tried the install you mentioned but it says I need a newer service pack. I'm on SP4.

Comment: Try [this one](http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/windows/Mercurial-2.0.2.exe). Also, even 12 year old machines can run Linux. I recommend installing one :)

Comment: I wish I had found that EXE a week ago! Now its working and no need to have tried to build it from source (which is painfull). BTW I'm already a Linux fan, just didn't want to wipe my installation. Disk space is tight. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, happy to be of help. Please accept the comment I converted into an answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{adding my comment as Answer}

When there's an exe available, it's easier to install than by source.

I recommend installing the official exe from the Mercurial site, built with InnoSetup so supports everything from Windows 2000 to Windows 8.

[Download link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/windows/Mercurial-2.0.2.exe)

Comment: Yes but, unfortunately, I found the .MSI file first.