# CythonGSL/ Using GSL on Windows via Cython

Tags: python, windows, cython, gsl

**Machine Configuration:** 
My config is windows 7 x64, with python 2.7 and cython 0.18 (all 64 bit ) installed. I also have MS C++ 2008 Visual Studio installed.

I have the GSL binaries and have Path pointed to the GSL\Bin.

I am using MS VS 2008 + SDK 7.0 to compile cython .pyx files. I use the SDK 7.0 command prompt to compile to c and cython.

**Problem**
However at compilation time I get a LINK error 2019, which indicates the header files in the GSL folder are not being found .

**My Attempts**
To resolve this I downloaded CythonGSL. using "from cythonGSL cimport *" didnt work. I went to the init file for this package and changed the directories it appears to be searching for to fit where I have installed GSL.
I have updated the setup.py as shown on the CythonGSL readme.

This **hasnt worked** either!!
At compile time, it says gsl.lib not found.

Any idea how i can fix this?

One option is if I could point a static address for example, in place of

```
    cdef extern from "libcalg/queue.h":
       with
    cdef extern from "FUll File Path/queue.h":
```

That doesnt work for now.

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Distutils import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import cython_gsl
import numpy as np
setup(

    include_dirs = [cython_gsl.get_include(), np.get_include()],
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("lda_gibbs_cython",
                             ["lda_gibbs_cython.pyx"],
                             libraries=cython_gsl.get_libraries(),
                             library_dirs=[cython_gsl.get_library_dir()],
                             include_dirs=[cython_gsl.get_cython_include_dir()])]
    )
```

The only difference is I include np.get
_include()

My .pyx file : (borrowed for testing from https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL/blob/master/examples/gibbs.pyx  )

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
from scipy.special import gammaln
from cython_gsl cimport *

cdef gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937)
```

Error message from the Cython GSL attempt:

```
D:\LDA\pythonLDA>setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning lda_gibbs_cython.pyx to lda_gibbs_cython.c
building 'lda_gibbs_cython' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nolog
o /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages -IC:/GSL/include -IC
:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Pytho
n27\PC /Tclda_gibbs_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cytho
n.obj
lda_gibbs_cython.c
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_deprecated_api.h(8) :
 Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECA
TED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
lda_gibbs_cython.c(2812) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '__int64'
 to 'long', possible loss of data
lda_gibbs_cython.c(4811) : warning C4101: 'getbuffer_cobj' : unreferenced local
variable
lda_gibbs_cython.c(4842) : warning C4101: 'releasebuffer_cobj' : unreferenced lo
cal variable
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /n
ologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:/GSL/lib /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\
Python27\PCbuild\amd64 gsl.lib gslcblas.lib /EXPORT:initlda_gibbs_cython build\t
emp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cython.obj /OUT:D:\LDA\pythonLDA\lda_
gibbs_cython.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cython.lib /
MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cython.pyd.manifest /MAN
IFEST
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gsl.lib'
error: command 'link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

**GCC Attempt**

I installed TDM-GCC so i could use the standard cmd window:

.pyx, and setup.py remain the same.I had an issue documented and resolved here [-mno-cygwin : gcc building Mercurial (Windows 2000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916133/mno-cygwin-gcc-building-mercurial-windows-2000) . Still no cigar. I dont know if this should be a separate question - will move if the experts think so.

```
D:\LDA\pythonLDA>setup.py build_ext --inplace -c mingw32
running build_ext
skipping 'lda_gibbs_cython.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'lda_gibbs_cython' extension
C:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages -IC:/GSL/i
nclude -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include
-IC:\Python27\PC -c lda_gibbs_cython.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_g
ibbs_cython.o
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cython.def
C:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cyt
hon.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lda_gibbs_cython.def -LC:/GSL/lib -LC:\Py
thon27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lpython27 -l -o D:\LDA\pythonLDA\lda_gibbs_cython.pyd
gcc: error: D:\LDA\pythonLDA\lda_gibbs_cython.pyd: No such file or direct
ory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only used `CythonGSL` - the current version (https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL/blob/master/cython_gsl/__init__.py) reads environmental variable `LIB_GSL` to determine the location of `GSL` directory. Make sure you have `LIB_GSL` environmental variable to point your main `GSL` folder (not `\bin` folder). For example, `LIB_GSL=C:/GSL`. And then you have to add `C:\GSL\bin` to your `PATH`. I have a [blog post](http://blog.joonro.net/en/2013/03/28/windows__installing_gsl_for_cythongsl.html) with detailed explanation.

**More explanations from Chat Discussion:** `TDM-GCC` + `EPD` + `GSL` (with a minor change - GSL files have to be at `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\`. This works perfectly for 64 bit windows 7.

Using the Windows binaries which were probably compiled on MS VS C++ 2008 could lead to conflict with `mingw64` compiled C++ programs.

---

**More explanation of the setup** (Added)

In general, it is much easier to use a scientific python distribution such as [Python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) (Free), [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) (successor of EPD, limited Free version), or [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda) (Free except advanced packages) than to install individual packages on top of vanilla python. It seems all three distributions come with MinGW, so you should be good to if you don't need openmp support for Cython, and if you do, you can install [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net).

In terms of `GSL`, you can download binary `GSL` from [oscats](https://code.google.com/p/oscats/downloads/list) projects. It has both 32 and 64 bit binaries with devel headers.

My setup is `Anaconda` + `TDM-GCC` + `GSL` (from [oscats](https://code.google.com/p/oscats/downloads/list) projects) and it has been working very well.

Comment: Joon, Thanks for responding. I wonder if this has to do with the SDK command prompt not getting to the environment variables. DO you have a similar C++ set up on Windows? May good karma befall you :-). By the way the link you attached doesnt seem to work , but this one does. https://raw.github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL/master/cython_gsl/__init__.py

Comment: Thanks I fixed the link. No I'm using TDM-GCC. Your ``setup.py`` does not look right - please try using the example ``setup.py`` at https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL README.

Comment: Tried with the setup file - didnt quite work.  See changes in the question above. Thanks for the TDM-GCC tip.I read somewhere that MS VS 2008 was used to compile python 2.7 x64, and so only c files using the same runtime would work. But it seems TDM GCC would work. I wonder if i use TDM GCC 64 bit with the normal command prompt would work (As I could then compile using the normal command prompt, should be able to locate environment variables easily). On the other hand I am no expert on this stuff !

Comment: So i tried the TDM-GCC - now the standard command prompt (not the sdk one) wants vcvarsall.bat...scylla and charibdis.

Comment: Your new error message says ``gcc: error: D:\LDA\pythonLDA\lda_gibbs_cython.pyd: No such file or direct
ory``, so it looks like it is missing a ``.pyd`` file which is a definition file. Are you trying to share cdef class across different cython modules? (because usually you don't need ``.pyd`` file) Take a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html.

Comment: I am not an expert either, but another thing is when I compile my Cython code with TDM-GCC I just use ``python setup.py build_ext --inplace``. Hope you figure this out.

Comment: Thanks Joon, i think cython does .pyx -> .c -> .pyd . I can then import .pyd into python.Or so I understand. used python setup.py build_ext --inplace with and without -c mingw32. Doesnt work yet.Shall cogitate some more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28061/discussion-between-joon-and-pythonometrist)