# GSL on windows can't find header files

Tags: windows, anaconda, cygwin, cython, gsl

I am trying to install the GSL library on windows, ultimately to get this project running: https://github.com/paulohubert/bayeseg.

However, i keep running into the error `Cannot open include file: 'gsl/gsl_mode.h': No such file or directory`

I tried downloading the GSL library mentioned in the github and setting LIB_GSL to the location as well as adding it to my path before installing cythongsl as mentioned in a previous answer ([CythonGSL/ Using GSL on Windows via Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910259/cythongsl-using-gsl-on-windows-via-cython)). I also tried downloading GSL from cygwin and https://code.google.com/p/oscats/downloads/list to no avail.

Note1: When i try to build and install cythonGSL (python setup.py build) i get the following warnings: `C:\toolkits\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'setup_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\toolkits\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)`,

and when i try to install the unittests i get the same `No such file or directory` error as i started with.

Note2: It seems cythongsl is integrated in anaconda since pip won't allow me to uninstall/reinstall it. Can it be pointing to the wrong GSL directory here?

I am trying this with anaconda 3.7.6 on a windows 10 machine.

**Steps taken to install gsl**:

1) I install MSYS2 with MinGW-w64

2) I update MYSYS2 with "*pacman -Su*" and update MinGW with "*pacman -Syu git make mingw-w64-x86_64-{gcc,cmake,icu,jemalloc,zlib}*"

3) I download the latest gsl and unpack it in the MSYS directory using the following commands in the MSYS-mingw64 shell:

```
$wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-latest.tar.gz

$mv gsl-latest.tar.gz ~/

$cd

$tar -zxvf gsl-latest.tar.gz

$cd ~/gsl-2.6

$./configure

$make

$make check

$make install
```

Make check does fail at a point with the following error:
[image]
The contents of spmatrix/test-suite.log is:

```
======================================
   gsl 2.6: spmatrix/test-suite.log
======================================

# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0

.. contents:: :depth: 2

FAIL: test
==========

FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[53,107](COO) [289]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[53,107](CSC) [290]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[53,107](CSR) [291]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[53,107](COO) [1313]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[53,107](CSC) [1314]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[53,107](CSR) [1315]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[40,20](COO) [1607]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[40,20](CSC) [1608]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[40,20](CSR) [1609]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[40,20](COO) [2631]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[40,20](CSC) [2632]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[40,20](CSR) [2633]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[30,30](COO) [2925]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[30,30](CSC) [2926]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_long_double_fscanf[30,30](CSR) [2927]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[30,30](COO) [3949]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[30,30](CSC) [3950]
FAIL: gsl_spmatrix_complex_long_double_fscanf[30,30](CSR) [3951]
```

However, i find [here](https://github.com/CNMAT/gsl/blob/master/INSTALL) that *With Mingw/MSYS some floating point issues have been reported which cause failures in the monte/ test directory.*, so i assume this is just a test error.

4) I find the header files installed in C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gsl, so i add this to path

5) I also add the environment variable LIB_GSL pointing to the project directory C:\msys64\mingw64\include (for cythongsl).

6) In clone [CythonGSL](https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL) and navigate there in anaconda prompt

7) Following the installation guide i run

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

8) i try to build the unittest with `python setup_test.py build`, but get the error `Cannot open include file: 'gsl/gsl_mode.h': No such file or directory`

9) Same error is seen when trying to use gsl for the installation of https://github.com/paulohubert/bayeseg.

Comment: do not mix Anaconda (that is not cygwin) with Cygwin. As it seems that you are trying to build a NOT cygwin program, I do not see the value to install Cygwin GSL packages

Comment: Ok, i am not really an expert in cygwin. I assumed i could use it to get the C libraries and simply point to them in my environment variables/path. Any idea why this wouldn't work?

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: I use anaconda and CythonGSL (at least i try). Based on your advice, i moved away from the cygwin approach and now use MSYS-mingw. I updated the question with a comprehensive list of the steps i take. Thanks for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: look on `test-suite.log` for details on the failing test. You can also run `make -i check` to run all tests and not stop at first error.

Comment: by using `make -i check` i saw it was failing at a later stage because cmp was missing, so i fixed this by installing diffutils (`pacman -S diffutils`). The spmatrix still fails however and i can't see from the test-suite log what is causing the failure. The testsuite log is inserted below the error